# UITableView reloaded before NSoperationQueue starts

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsoperationqueue

I am using `NSOperationQueue` for calling a service in background in `viewWillAppear`(I also tried putting it in `viewDidLoad` for that matter). I am populating the `UITableView` based on results I get from service. When I debug the application, the table gets called first and then the **operationQueue**. In this way the table is empty for me. How to populate the table after **operationQueue** does its job.

Here is the code :

**viewWillAppear** :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    operationQueue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    ParseOperation *obj=[[ParseOperation alloc] initWithMembers:ID];
    [operationQueue addOperation:obj];
    [obj release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the "reloadTable" as a specific operation with dependency on the parse operation, immediately after the parse operation definition and just before starting the queue (so for safety initialize the queue as suspended and then start it only once all operations have been added):

```
// ... inside your operation code definition
NSInvocationOperation *reloadOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myReload) object:nil];
[reloadOp addDependency:obj] // adding here the parse operation as a dependency
[operationQueue addOperation:reloadOp];
```

The "myReload" operation needs to be defined as a stand-alone method in order to ensure that the reloadTable method is called in the main thread:

`-(void)myReload {
  [table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}`

In this way your reload code will be run only after the parse operation terminates. This is useful if you have more operations to be run and all them needs to be executed before the table reload. Note that the dependency is unaware of the fact that the operation terminated normally or has been cancelled.

Another good way you may consider is to define a GCD serial queue and add the two blocks in sequence (first block is parsing, second block is table reload). In such case GCD will guarantee the proper execution order of the two blocks (FIFO).

Comment: Is the above code of NSInvocationOperation to be placed in viewWillAppear after ParseOperation *obj=[[ParseOperation alloc] initWithMembers:ID];
Because I tried this just now and it didn't work. Still the table methods are being called first and I am not able to get output on table. I also created myReload function in same class but it is not working.

Comment: Your table reload will be called automatically in any case (especially if you are using UITableViewController). But you shouldn't worry about it, as initially you will still show an empty table. But after the operation completes, the new reload should be called again and in such case you should see your table populated. The two operations should be created together (first ParseOperation, then reload operation), then added to the queue and then the queue must be started (I recommend, when you create the queue, to set it as "suspended". Do you really need to use NSOperation? why not GCD?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Actually I was not adding NSInvocationOperation to my operationQueue. It is working absolutely fine.

Comment: I have to use operationQueuebecause I have to call service regularly after short duration. Firstly I was doing it with NSTimer. But then I heard about operationQueue. If you knowledge about GCD(which I have no idea about) please share it with me here. I'll definitely try it.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use GCD as a NSOperationQueue replacement in most cases, thanks to its great flexibility. NSOperationQueue becomes mandatory in two cases: when you want to have the possibility to cancel an operation (this is not possible with GCD) or when your operations require NSRunLoop, e.g. for NSURLConnection with delegate set. Generally speaking GCD is far better, easier to setup and control.

Comment: Thanks for spreading info. I am facing another problem. The above operation is being called only once. Any idea?

Comment: I went through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987283/why-is-my-nsoperationqueue-not-behaving-correctly-in-ios-4-0) link but didn't get much idea. Can you help me more on this?

Comment: It is better you open a new question, post a larger section of your code (including the part of the code that triggers the repetition and latest modifications) and add the link to the new question here as a comment.

Comment: :) I have already posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209979/check-if-nstimer-selector-has-finished-working).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a completion bloc for your NSOperation. Where you have to call reload data on your table view.

```
- (void)setCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))block
```

Edit:

add this

```
[obj setCompletionBlock:^{
                                NSLog(@"I have fnish");
                                 [self.tableView reloadData];
                                } 
     ];
```

Comment: How to do that? I am using operationQueue for the first time. It will be helpful if you can me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Call `[tableView reloadData]` after the `operationQueue` finished.